# Why does NSTextView not always wrap text fluently while resizing?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I've stumbled upon a behavior in `NSTextView` that does not seem intended, or that I at least do not understand the reasoning behind.

When you have a large body of text in an `NSTextView` and you resize the control/window, the wrapping of words only happens fluently and immediately *while* resizing when the text is scrolled near the top. If you scroll far down in the text, it does not, and it doesn't seem to "commit" the wrapping until you release and finish resizing.

Is there some internal limitation, or is this a bug?

The issue seems to be reproducible:

macOS 10.15.4, Xcode 11.4.1

1. Create a new macOS App project
2. Put an `NSTextView` on the default generated view controller (doesn't matter which of the 3: rich, plain or default) and constrain it so that it resizes with the window (top, bottom, leading, trailing)
3. Run the application and paste a large body of text into the text view (for example: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/12281/pg12281.txt)
4. Scroll to the top of the `NSTextView` and observe how the text wraps *while* resizing the window
5. Scroll to the bottom and observe how it only wraps *after* resizing the window

Hoping there's any Cocoa detectives out there who can provide some enlightenment on this one.

**EDIT:**
As per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1402967-ensurelayout), it states that "the layout manager reserves the right to perform layout for larger ranges". I take it that this means it is indeed intended as a performance consideration.

Is there any way to determine what the limit is, though?

Comment: Well, if you have a large amount of text, it takes time to relayout all the text above the visible portion, and the results of that relayout might affect the appearance of the visible portion.  I'm not sure why you expect this to be instantaneous...?

Comment: Obviously. But you can give it all the time in the world, it still doesn't trigger a layout until you finally let go of the mouse (as opposed to continuously while dragging, however slow it may be, which is the behavior I expect and do see initially).

Comment: Does enabling non-contiguous layout for the NSLayoutManager via `allowsNonContiguousLayout` change the behavior?

Comment: @Mattie no, it does not appear to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: You could try subclassing NSScrollView to render the text into multiple containers.

```c
 NSTextStorage *storage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:string];
     NSLayoutManager *manager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
     [storage addLayoutManager:manager];

     NSInteger i = 0;

     while (YES) {
         NSTextContainer *container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
         [manager addTextContainer:container];

         NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height) textContainer:container];

         [self.contentView addSubview:textView];
         i++;

         NSRange range = [manager glyphRangeForTextContainer:container];
            if ( range.length + range.location == string.length )
                break;
    }
```

Then, while resizing the window, you can call NSLayoutManager to ensure the layout only for visible containers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does not seem to make a difference, though.

Comment: I guess the only solution is to subclass NSLayoutManager, then. You could also try subclassing `NSScrollView` (like in TextEdit example) to build the view using multiple `NSTextContainer`s, and see if that helps. It's still the same layout manager, though.

Comment: The same wrapping behavior can actually be observed in TextEdit.app: no continuous wrapping while resizing window when scrolled to bottom of large text. I think the conclusion is that continuous wrapping can only be achieved by implementing layout from scratch in order to circumvent whatever rules the `ensureLayout`-family of functions have put in place to prevent it.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I did a quick and dirty test with multiple text containers (updated above), and had some luck, but it just seems to lead to other graphical glitches.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I don't think this is suitable for my particular use-case, but there might be a clue to a clever solution somewhere in there.